# A bash script to rename files from different directories at once

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rename

If I have a directory named `/all_images`, and inside this directory there's a ton of directories, all the directories named `dish_num` as shown below. and inside each dish directory, there's one image named `rgb.png`. How can i rename all the image files to be the name of its directory.

#### Before

```
|
├── dish_1
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_2
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_3
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_4
│   └── rgb.png
└── dish_5
    └── rgb.png
```

#### After

```
|
├── dish_1
│   └── dish_1.png
├── dish_2
│   └── dish_2.png
├── dish_3
│   └── dish_3.png
├── dish_4
│   └── dish_4.png
└── dish_5
    └── dish_5.png
```

Answer (score 3):

WARNING: Make sure you have backups before running code you got *someplace* on the Internet!

```
find /all_images -name rgb.png -execdir sh -c 'mv rgb.png $(basename $PWD).png' \;
```

where

- `find /all_images` will start looking from the directory "/all_images"
- `-name rbg.png` will look anywhere for anything named "rbg.png"
- optionally use `-type f` to restrict results to only files
- `-exedir` in every directory where you got a hit, execute the following:
- `sh -c` shell script
- `mv` move, or "rename" in this case
- `rgb.png` file named "rgb.png"
- `$(basename $PWD).png` output of "basename $PWD", which is the last section of the $PWD - the current directory - and append ".png" to it
- `\;` terminating string for the find loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to benefited from your multi-core processors, consider using `xargs` instead of `find -execdir` to process files concurrently.

Here is a solution composed of `find`, `xargs`, `mv`, `basename` and `dirname`.

```sh
find all_images -type f -name rgb.png |
  xargs -P0 -I@ sh -c 'mv @ $(dirname @)/$(basename $(dirname @)).png'
```

1. `find all_images -type f -name rgb.png` prints a list of file paths whose filename is exactly `rgb.png`.
2. `xargs -P0 -I@ CMD...` executes `CMD` in a parallel mode with `@` replaced by path names from `find` command. Please refer to `man xargs` for more information.

   > -P maxprocs
   > Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at once.  If maxprocs is set to 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible.
3. `dirname all_images/dash_4/rgb.png` becomes `all_images/dash_4`
4. `basename all_images/dash_4` becomes `dash_4`

## Demo

```sh
mkdir all_images && seq 5 |
  xargs -I@ sh -c 'mkdir all_images/dash_@ && touch all_images/dash_@/rgb.png'
tree
find all_images -type f -name rgb.png |
  xargs -P0 -I@ sh -c 'mv @ $(dirname @)/$(basename $(dirname @)).png'
tree
```

### Output

```
.
└── all_images
    ├── dash_1
    │   └── rgb.png
    ├── dash_2
    │   └── rgb.png
    ├── dash_3
    │   └── rgb.png
    ├── dash_4
    │   └── rgb.png
    └── dash_5
        └── rgb.png

.
└── all_images
    ├── dash_1
    │   └── dash_1.png
    ├── dash_2
    │   └── dash_2.png
    ├── dash_3
    │   └── dash_3.png
    ├── dash_4
    │   └── dash_4.png
    └── dash_5
        └── dash_5.png

6 directories, 5 files
```